# How do you get a metric of cloudwatch log group size?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to track and alert if my logs go awry.  But I can't find a way of tracking the stored bytes for a log group.  Is it possible to even add that as a metric?

[image]

Comment: I looked at this recently - my conclusion was that there was no easy way to get the size of a log group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The supported Metrics for CloudWatch log groups that might suit your use case are `IncomingBytes` and `IncomingLogEvents` for event ingestion.

If you want to monitor event forwarding to your subscribers as well there are metrics available too.

See full documentation on supported metrics: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CloudWatch-Logs-Monitoring-CloudWatch-Metrics.html

The actual log group size seems to only be available via API [`decribe-log-groups`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/describe-log-groups.html).

Comment: I wonder if there can be a lambda created that would push that data to cloudwatch easily.

Comment: A alternative but rather hacky way without a lot of implementation effort could be to set up a budget alert for this log group for the Usage type (in this case "CloudWatch > Region-TimedStoarage-byteHrs (GB/Month)") and filter on a custom cost tag that identifies your log group you are interested in. However this won't let you get the metric in CloudWatch but only via E-mail or SNS Topic. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/budgets-create.html#create-usage-budget for details

Answer (score 0):

[This newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73957028/aws-cloudwatch-difference-log-data-ingested-and-actual-size-of-log-groups) is very useful. AWS Support told "smk081"

> Stored Bytes/Stored GB do not update in real time. There is a delay of
> at least 24 hours on average but it can vary some.

Also

> IncomingBytes is the raw, uncompressed bytes while the Stored Bytes is
> compressed